# Problem with running Socket IO through gunicorn on Fly.io

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, gevent, flask-socketio

I am trying to host my flask website on fly.io. My website uses the flask_socketio library and needs a 2 ended connection with the client and server, so this is the gunicorn command I use in the Profile:

```
    web: gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 main:app
```

This causes the following error in my fly.io log

```
    TypeError: Cannot convert greenlet.greenlet to gevent._gevent_c_greenlet_primitives.SwitchOutGreenletWithLoop
```

I have searched stack overflow and found this person having a practically identical problem using Hikaru. Unfortunatly no one gave him an answer and he solved the problem on his own by updating python and re-installing gunicorn.
I tried this, without any positive outcome.
Python: 3.10.9

```
gevent==22.10.2
gevent-websocket==0.10.1
greenlet==2.0.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

Comment: You are not providing any information, so it is impossible to diagnose your problem. You need to include the full stack trace of the error and the code that instantiates the Socket.IO server as a start.

Comment: Similar issue here. Code works ok locally but not on digital ocean server